# Jenkins job showing exception: Caught exception evaluating: it.transientActions

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, openshift

I am seeing an exception in Jenkins job while using post webhooks with bitbucket. Here are some details regarding the job:

1. Jenkins is setup on Kubernetes and pods are used as executors.
2. It is a pipeline job.
3. `Trigger builds remotely` is enabled with a token.
4. A post webhook is setup in bitbucket for triggering a build when a commit is pushed.

Now, the jobs are getting triggered correctly after a change is pushed in the git repository but the pipeline fails with an exception:

```
2020-06-03 11:13:50.494+0000 [id=148260]        WARNING h.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression#evaluate: Caught exception evaluating: it.transientActions in /job/aaaa/11/console. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

The complete exception is:

```
2020-06-03 11:13:50.494+0000 [id=148260]        WARNING h.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression#evaluate: Caught exception evaluating: it.transientActions in /job/aaaa/11/console. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: you must override the new overload of isApplicable in hudson.plugins.project_inheritance.projects.rebuild.RebuildValidatorSuppressor
        at com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildValidator.isApplicable(RebuildValidator.java:50)
        at com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildActionFactory.createFor(RebuildActionFactory.java:61)
        at hudson.model.Run.getTransientActions(Run.java:385)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1271.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:314)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTArrayAccess.evaluateExpr(ASTArrayAccess.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:75)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
        at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:58)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CompressTag.doTag(CompressTag.java:44)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:56)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:43)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Facet$1.dispatch(Facet.java:238)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$9.dispatch(MetaClass.java:456)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.slowrequest.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(SlowRequestFilter.java:37)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:243)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Console output is something like:

```
Running on build-11-vmn8l-5gctd in /home/jenkins/workspace/aaaa
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential 03aa7ed0-bab1-498b-a728-3675fb713390
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/aaaa # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials bitbucket auth
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials bitbucket auth
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://abc.bitbucket.com:8080/scm/abc/abc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 5ae7500e13fa8a118d5f0e887a60e29a524f73e6 (origin/master)
Commit message: "Test jenkins exceptions"
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
 > git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5ae7500e13fa8a118d5f0e887a60e29a524f73e6
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: 3014abff-c3a5-434c-a61a-5c87b78e27df 
Finished: FAILURE
```

The same Jenkinsfile works fine when I don't use build trigger and paste it directly in `Pipeline Script`  source. The area where failure occurs in Jenkinsfile is (please do not try to do a syntactical validation of this snippet, this is just a small part where the issue is getting noticed):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud 'openshift'
            label "build-${env.BUILD_ID}"
            defaultContainer 'jnlp'
            yamlFile "build-pod.yaml"
        }
    }

    environment{
      OC_NAMESPACE='lol'
      ARTIFACTORY_API_CREDS = credentials('3014abff-c3a5-434c-a61a-5c87b78e27df')
    }

    stages{

      stage("Lint Helm Chart") {
        steps{
          container('helm') {
            script{
              sh "helm lint ./helm-charts/abc/"
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

A few more logs I noticed when the failure occurred:

```
2020-06-03 11:31:35.635+0000 [id=34]    INFO    hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner#lambda$update$6: Kubernetes Pod Template provisioning successfully completed. We have now 2 computer(s)
2020-06-03 11:31:35.717+0000 [id=148769]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Created Pod: cicddemo/build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:31:35.817+0000 [id=148812]        INFO    o.internal.platform.Platform#log: ALPN callback dropped: HTTP/2 is disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
2020-06-03 11:31:42.374+0000 [id=148814]        INFO    h.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler#run: Accepted JNLP4-connect connection #52 from /100.64.53.1:51368
2020-06-03 11:31:42.647+0000 [id=148769]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Pod is running: cicddemo/build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:31:42.653+0000 [id=148769]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (0/100): build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:31:43.761+0000 [id=148769]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesLauncher#launch: Waiting for agent to connect (1/100): build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:32:04.672+0000 [id=148820]        WARNING o.j.r.u.AnonymousClassWarnings#warn: Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser$1 in file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/git/WEB-INF/lib/git.jar; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
2020-06-03 11:32:08.904+0000 [id=148815]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:32:09.105+0000 [id=148767]        INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#1160] for build-12-js0sx-5396k terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2020-06-03 11:32:09.169+0000 [id=148815]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#deleteSlavePod: Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent cicddemo/build-12-js0sx-5396k
Terminated Kubernetes instance for agent cicddemo/build-12-js0sx-5396k
Disconnected computer build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:32:09.169+0000 [id=148815]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesSlave#_terminate: Disconnected computer build-12-js0sx-5396k
2020-06-03 11:32:10.012+0000 [id=148836]        INFO    o.c.j.p.k.p.PodTemplateStepExecution$PodTemplateCallback#finished: Removing pod template build-12-js0sx from cloud openshift
2020-06-03 11:32:11.258+0000 [id=148836]        INFO    o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#finish: aaaa #12 completed: FAILURE
2020-06-03 11:32:11.258+0000 [id=148836]        WARNING h.model.listeners.RunListener#report: RunListener failed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: you must override the new overload of isApplicable in hudson.plugins.project_inheritance.projects.rebuild.RebuildValidatorSuppressor
        at com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildValidator.isApplicable(RebuildValidator.java:50)
        at com.sonyericsson.rebuild.Rebuilder.onCompleted(Rebuilder.java:53)
        at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:209)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.finish(WorkflowRun.java:586)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.access$900(WorkflowRun.java:133)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$GraphL.onNewHead(WorkflowRun.java:998)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.notifyListeners(CpsFlowExecution.java:1463)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$3.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:458)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:35)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It was related to Artifactory credentials ID - `3014abff-c3a5-434c-a61a-5c87b78e27df`. This ID was incorrect and there was no credential with this ID in Jenkins because of which these exceptions were shown.